# Can't ctrl+drag into ViewController.h from second Viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am building an iOS app for fun and here is where I run into trouble. I can insert an outlet and action in the ViewController.h files directly from my first View Controller through the ctrl+drag method; however, when I try ctrl+drag on the second ViewController it will not allow me.

Ctrl+drag on first ViewController

[image]

Ctrl+drag on second ViewController

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong document open in the assistant editor. It should be ViewController.h, but you are displaying UIViewController.h.

Check you have correctly set your second view controller to your custom class ViewController using the Identity Inspector (third of the right hand utility panels) then make sure it's header file is the document you are displaying on the right.

*update*

From your comments, you are having difficulty setting the second view controller to a custom class.

Here is how you select it in the storyboard. Note that you are selecting the *View Controller*, not it's topmost *View*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately, that did not work. Whenever I try to change it to ViewController.h, it still will not let me. Also, the custom class changes back to UIView whenever I change it to ViewController it changes back to UIView.

Comment: UIView or UIViewController? Are you certain you have selected the UIViewController and not it's top-level view when you try to change the class?

Comment: UIView. How would I change the class because I don't think I did it right. I changed the class from the Identity Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the class in the field "Class." You then need to press ENTER to take  effect. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2MnR.png)